# Can we use verb -ing before that? "saying that" / "showing that"

Tags: gerunds

> The final packaging recycling data for 2016 has been published by the EA, **showing that** overall, the packaging recycling rate rose by 6.8% on 2015 and now stands at almost 65% ... [link](http://www.ciwm-journal.co.uk/provisional-figures-show-2016-packaging-targets-met/)

> A country survey on CME systems in Europe, including 10 European countries, has been conducted by EACIC, **showing that** a high percentage ... [link](http://eacic.eu/index.php?page=history)

> Moreover, several theoretical papers have been written **showing that** the observed phenomena ... [link](http://web.mit.edu/14.193/www/WorldCongress-IEW-Version6Oct03.pdf)

I see a lot of news and books are using *present participle (-ing)* with *that*.

I checked [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/that-clauses) and I found the following:

> We use **that** as a conjunction to link a **verb, adjective or noun** with the following clause.
>
> - Verb + that-clause: They **said that** four million ...
> - Adjective + that-clause: It’s **important (that)** we look ..
> - Noun + that-clause: .. treatment in the **hope that** he will ...

My question: Can we use *verb -ing* before *that*? is the following correct?

> He is writing a new book **showing that** ...

Comment: Yes, **showing that...** is grammatical.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can follow a word ending in "-ing" with "that."

However, in your your listed examples and suggestion, "showing" is not a verb. It is a present participle.

> A participle is a verb form that functions as an adjective by modifying nouns and pronouns. A participle can be either a present participle or a past participle. A participial phrase includes the participle, plus any modifiers and complements.

http://www.k12reader.com/term/participle-phrase/

So, in your first example sentence:

> The final packaging recycling data for 2016 has been published by the EA, showing that overall, the packaging recycling rate rose by 6.8% on 2015 and now stands at almost 65% ...

"Data" is the subject, "has been published" is the verb phrase, and "showing" is the present participle at the beginning of a participial phrase that describes the noun, "data."

In your second example sentence:

> A country survey on CME systems in Europe, including 10 European countries, has been conducted by EACIC, showing that a high percentage ...

"Survey" is the subject, "has been conducted" is the verb phrase, and "showing" is the participle at the beginning of a participial phrase that describes the noun, "survey."